# Why does select on input with value fire two events in chromium?

Tags: javascript, html, chromium

I'm testing this in chromium 43.

The following code fires just **one event** when I press the select button:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('select', function(ev) {
        console.log(ev, ev.timeStamp);
    });
</script>
<input type="text"><button onclick="document.querySelector('input').select()">select</button>
```

However, if I add a value to the input type=text, I get **two events** and the only thing that changes between the events is the timeStamp property:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('select', function(ev) {
    console.log(ev, ev.timeStamp);
  });
</script>
<input type="text" value="test"><button onclick="document.querySelector('input').select()">select</button>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and what is the rational behind it?

Comment: Been trying to figure this out since you posted the question. Feeling that it might be a browser bug...

Comment: Maybe related to this issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265907/make-select-on-input-field-not-copy-to-clipboard-in-chromium On linux it also seems to copy, whenever you select, the current buffer to the primary buffer and found this weird behavior with two events while trying to make the input not copy on first select, but only on double click. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what's happening is that there are two types of `select event` being fired, but since the `Event` object has a limited set of details, they look exactly the same. But it looks like there's one `select` event being triggered when you change `selectionRange` of the input, and one select event triggered when the actual text selection changes (in this case because focus is activated on input because of the selection change). That last one is the one not being fired when the input is empty - since there's no text, there's no change in the text selection.

You can break it down by putting the `select()` on `mousedown`. Since it occurs on `mousedown` on the button, the focus isn't made on the input but stays on the button. But an event is fired nonetheless. Then if you just add a `focus()` on `mouseup` for example, you don't change the `selectionRange` of the input but actual text gets selected and fires a select event.
Or, if in your click handler you call select() and then focus() on the button you'll have only one event as well.
You can see here these behaviors:

https://jsfiddle.net/k292po9a/6/

That being said, it certainly looks like a bug, it should be handled by Chrome so that only one event is fired.